# Avoid duplication in SQL Server

Tags: select, sql-server-2012

I got the below result when i run this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PT.F_PRO AS F_PRODUCT, PT.F_TEXT_CODE AS F_TEXT_CODE, PHT.F_PHRASE AS F_PHRASE FROM T_PROD_TEXT PT
LEFT JOIN T_P_LINKAGE PHL
    ON PT.F_TEXT_CODE = PHL.F_TEXT_CODE
INNER JOIN T_P_TRANSLATIONS PHT
    ON PHL.F_PHRASE_ID = PHT.F_PHRASE_ID
WHERE PT.F_DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.F_LANGUAGE = 'EN'

OUTPUT

F_PRODUCT   F_TEXT_CODE F_PHRASE
294264_B    MANU0008    Alcoa, Inc
294264_B    MANU0012    BioSensory
00091A      MANU0006    3M Company
00094A      MANU0006    4M Company
00094A      MANU0006    5M Company
```

The above query returns duplication in F_PRODUCT COLUMN.i want to display F_product without duplication. only one  record should display for each F_product.(First record) without using top command

```
Required Output

F_PRODUCT   F_TEXT_CODE F_PHRASE
294264_B    MANU0008    Alcoa, Inc.
00091A      MANU0006    3M Company|par
```

Comment: What will you order by to determine which one is "first"?

Comment: Also do you have a typo or should you also be getting `00094A` vs `00091A`

Comment: sorry 00094A only not 00091A

Comment: it should display first record of each f_product records

Comment: 00091A and also 00094A. If not you should explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to assign a number to each row within a group of f_pro. Then retrieve only rows that are number 1. You can change the `order by` if something else determines the order.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT PT.F_PRO AS F_PRODUCT, PT.F_TEXT_CODE AS F_TEXT_CODE, PHT.F_PHRASE AS F_PHRASE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PT.F_PRO ORDER BY PHT.F_PHRASE ASC) AS RowNum
  FROM T_PROD_TEXT PT
  LEFT JOIN T_P_LINKAGE PHL
      ON PT.F_TEXT_CODE = PHL.F_TEXT_CODE
  INNER JOIN T_P_TRANSLATIONS PHT
      ON PHL.F_PHRASE_ID = PHT.F_PHRASE_ID
  WHERE PT.F_DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.F_LANGUAGE = 'EN') dt
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PT.F_PRO AS F_PRODUCT, 
MIN(PT.F_TEXT_CODE) AS F_TEXT_CODE, 
MIN(PHT.F_PHRASE) AS F_PHRASE FROM T_PROD_TEXT PT
LEFT JOIN T_P_LINKAGE PHL
    ON PT.F_TEXT_CODE = PHL.F_TEXT_CODE
INNER JOIN T_P_TRANSLATIONS PHT
    ON PHL.F_PHRASE_ID = PHT.F_PHRASE_ID
WHERE PT.F_DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.F_LANGUAGE = 'EN'
group By PT.F_PRO;
```

is one way to do that. It doesn't do it for the "FIRST" since it is vague how would you define the "FIRST".

Comment: Thank you Very Much

Comment: is it possible to use not exists clause in the query.

Comment: @Ram, yes you can.